# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'asd'

Tags: django, django-models

I've looked for other questions, but they're just different errors.

I've been developing a simple forum app, and now I've come to the part where I can comment on topics. But then I realized that I have been missing the ForeignKey relationship to the topic from the comment. Then, I created a new ForeignKey but as usual, it asks me to give a default value. I was just about to add Blank and Null true, but then my hands just automatically give `asd` as a default. Now even when I succeed in making migrations with makemigrations, I got this error when making `migrate` how can I make this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the migration file created after makemigration. There is the field in the migration file.

For example:

```
field=models.ForeignKey(default="asd")
```

You should edit this section and re-run `migrate`

Comment: I didn't want my head all fussing up over this and since I haven't added any data related to that model. I just deleted everything related to comments in migrations. But yea, the fact is, it solved and thank you for letting me learn.

Answer (score 0):

The `ForeignKey` is a row in your table that somehow is a subset of integers. So if you add `ForeignKey` to one model after inserting data to that model (whithout default and null values) it will ask how do you want to add this row which is not null in your table's data and because this field is an integer type you should enter a valid integer in that field (not string or any other types). Note that the integer that you will enter as default value should be a valid choice (i.e. a `topic` record with that integer as primary key  or your related table's primary key that you want to connect a `ForeignKey` to it exists) and if not you can not run `migrate` because this time Django will raise `IntegrityError`.